# Authentication token always returning unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest

I am trying to use a bearer token at present and no matter what I do, I get a HTTP 401 unauthorized error.

I am following a [guide](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-jwt-in-asp-net-core-3-1/) on JWT implementation I have a extension method that handles the JWT.

```
public static class AuthenticationExtension 
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddTokenAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config) 
    {
        var secret = config.GetSection("JwtConfig").GetSection("secret").Value;

        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret);

        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false, 
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    // ValidIssuer = "localhost",
                    //ValidAudience = "localhost"
                };
        });

        return services;
    }
}
```

Also the following is the way the token controller generates the token obv I should be getting values from the header instead email and a password for example.

As that code be replaced if found in code could it not.

```
var  token = jwt.GenerateSecurityToken("fake@email.com");
```

In my `StartUp.cs` I simply have the following to add the middle ware to my config. In the services section I conduct a test

```
  services.AddTokenAuthentication(Configuration);
```

But as you see I get HTTP 401 unauthorised returned.

[image]

This is the code from the api/token controller.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TokenController : ControllerBase
{
    private IConfiguration _config;

    public TokenController(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string GetRandomToken()
    {
        var jwt = new JwtService(_config);
        var token = jwt.GenerateSecurityToken("fake@email.com");
        return token;
    }
}
```

Token from api/token

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImZha2VAZW1haWwuY29tIiwibmJmIjoxNTg2NjMzMTkwLCJleHAiOjE1ODY3MTk1OTAsImlhdCI6MTU4NjYzMzE5MH0.SPSErcPpD4f48sWFYQFVUBmTaVtCW8oDw4Np6Tncozo

This is my `appSettings.json` config I will of course be changing my secret once I have this setup.

Is this enough to secure a api or should you also use client id and secret in terms of api layer. HMAC style.

```
"JwtConfig": {
    "secret": "PDv7DrqznYL6nv7DrqzjnQYO9JxIsWdcjnQYL6nu0f",
    "expirationInMinutes": 1440   
},
```

Comment: You can validate your jwt token at https://jwt.io/. The token "Token from api/token" is invalid, so i think the error is correct. Start by making a token that is validated successfully at https://jwt.io/.

Comment: But I simply gerneated the token from the above code so what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I also failed like you did at first, eventually I followed [this tutorial](https://dev.to/_patrickgod/authentication-with-json-web-tokens-in-net-core-3-1-29bd) and with a few modifications I had a working code.

I used user Id as identifier and here are the parts in my code related to jwt authentication:

**UserService:**

```
    public class UserService : IUserService
{
    ...

    public IDataResult<AuthenticationResponse> Authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request)
    {
        UserDto userDto = _mapper.Map<UserDto>(user);

        AccessToken token = generateJwtToken(userDto);
        return new SuccessDataResult<AuthenticationResponse>(new AuthenticationResponse(userDto, token));
    }

    private AccessToken generateJwtToken(UserDto userDto)
    {
        AuthUser authUser = _mapper.Map<AuthUser>(userDto);
        return _jwtHelper.CreateToken(authUser);
    }

    ...
}
```

**JWTHelper:**

```
    public class JwtHelper
{
    ...
    public AccessToken CreateToken(AuthUser user)
    {
        _accessTokenExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_tokenOptions.ExpirationInMinutes);
        var securityKey = SecurityKeyHelper.CreateSecurityKey(_tokenOptions.SecurityKey);
        var signingCredentials = SigningCredentialsHelper.CreateSigningCredentials(securityKey);
        var jwt = CreateJwtSecurityToken(_tokenOptions, user, signingCredentials);
        var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);
        return new AccessToken
        {
            Token = token,
            Expiration = _accessTokenExpiration
        };
    }

    private JwtSecurityToken CreateJwtSecurityToken(TokenOptions tokenOptions, AuthUser user,
        SigningCredentials signingCredentials)
    {
        var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
            expires: _accessTokenExpiration,
            claims: SetClaims(user),
            signingCredentials: signingCredentials
        );
        return jwt;
    }

    private IEnumerable<Claim> SetClaims(AuthUser user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString());
        return claims;
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
{
public class Startup
{
    ...

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(
            options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("TokenOptions:SecurityKey")))
            };
        });
        ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(...);
        ...
    }
}
```